# Remember the last post I read

Tags: navigation, cookies

I am currently publishing a book series with WP (not in english). Books, chapters and subparts are arranged this way: Each book (category) is divided into chapters (subcategory) which is divided into subparts (post). 
The website is completely open and requires no user account / login. Comments are managed with the Disqus plugin.

Is there any way to create/update a cookie with navigation information, so when the reader leaves and returns the next day, the site automatically navigates to the last post?

EDIT:

MS Word 2013 has an implementation of a similar functionality. When opening a large document, an info box appears "Welcome back, pick up where you left off." That'd be a nice welcome for a loyal reader.

Comment: Your question is an interesting one. I have removed the part where you ask for a plugin, note that asking to recommend a plugin or theme is off topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this question so had a look at it myself. The best way I could think to go about it would be to use localstorage and jQuery to store the current URL and scroll position of the user. Then you could either run a check when they come back to that page or have a button like "continue reading" which would retrieve the URL and the scroll position sending the user to that exact point.

## JS

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
```

Check is local storage is supported

```
var storedResult = localStorage.getItem("location");
var storedURL = localStorage.getItem("url");
```

Get the Stored URL and Scroll Location

```
 if (storedURL !== 'undefined' && storedResult !== null) {
```

Check if the URL is stored
         var currentUrl = window.location.href;
Get the current URL

```
     if (currentUrl != storedURL) {
```

Check if the current URL and Stored URL Do Not match.

Send user to stored URL. You would probably want to trigger this on a "continue reading" button or something otherwise you could end up sending users where they dont wish to go.

```
}
    else if (storedResult !== 'undefined' && storedResult !== null) {
```

elseif check if the window scroll location is stored.

```
        $(window).scrollTop(storedResult);
```

scroll to that location.

```
}
 } 
    $(window).scroll(function () {
```

On scroll event

```
    var scrolledDown = window.scrollY;
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

get the window scroll potion and url

```
    localStorage.setItem("location", scrolledDown);
    localStorage.setItem("url", currentUrl);
```

store in local storage.

```
});

 } else {

    //No Web Storage Support.
 }
```

All together

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
//Check is local storage is supported

var storedResult = localStorage.getItem("location");
var storedURL = localStorage.getItem("url");
//Get the Stored URL and Scroll Location

 if (storedURL !== 'undefined' && storedResult !== null) {
     //Check if the URL is stored
     var currentUrl = window.location.href;
     //Get the current URL
     if (currentUrl != storedURL) {
         //Check if the current URL and Stored URL Do Not match.

         // send user to stored URL. You would probably want to trigger this on a "continue reading" button or something otherwise you could end up sending users where they dont wish to go.
     }

    else if (storedResult !== 'undefined' && storedResult !== null) {
        //elseif check if the window scroll location is stored.

        $(window).scrollTop(storedResult);
        //scroll to that location.
    }
 }

$(window).scroll(function () { 
    //On scroll event
    var scrolledDown = window.scrollY;
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    // get the window scroll potion and url
    localStorage.setItem("location", scrolledDown);
    localStorage.setItem("url", currentUrl);
    // store in local storage.
});

} else {
    // No Web Storage Support.
}
```

### Demo

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fg9uok4L/

#### Resources

jQuery .scrollTop: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/
jQuery .scroll: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
LocalStorage: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Not sure on performance with this not tested.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting suggestion. I will try to implement it, and will come back with further comments / acceptance.

Comment: Mark's solution successfully implemented at www.trollkrigen.no. The website has afront page, where a welcome-button now is displayed if navigation data is stored in local memory, which takes the guest to the correct page and page height. I have made a few adjustments to the code in order to achieve this. Mark's example has been very helpful.

Comment: Glad it was some help :)